# How to hold CheckBox checked status after page refresh?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am having a listview and trying to delete multiple data that is checked. But when pressing the Delete button the page is getting refreshed and the Checkbox is not getting checked so that data is not getting deleted. Here is my code:
Page Load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["username"] == null)
        Response.Redirect("admin-login");
    lblusername.Text = Session["username"].ToString();
    string nation;

         bindListview();

 }
```

Delete button code:

```
protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        foreach (ListViewDataItem Ldi in ListView1.Items)
        {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)(Ldi.FindControl("chkBxSelect"));
            HiddenField hdnFldCandidateID = (HiddenField)(Ldi.FindControl("hdnFldCandidateID"));
            string candidateID = hdnFldCandidateID.Value;

            if (cb.Checked)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Confirm", "Confirm();", true);
                con.Open();
                query = "delete from candidates where candidate_id=" + candidateID + "";
                cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                Response.Redirect("candidate-search");

            }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("Error:" + ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: this issue is so comun from asp.net enviroment , the problem are on postback call , that you have to do is validate no postback call and bind all data to checks , other solution you can use ajax call from controll or using wcf ajaxenableds or if you dont wann make all isssues , the solution is disable postback from button

Comment: Post your `page_load` event handler code here.

Comment: I am new in javascript. Will you please explain with sample?thanks

Comment: In your page_load, where you bind your data, be sure to check if not ispostback. e.g. if (!Page.IsPostBack) {databinding}  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9672522/disable-postback-on-asp-net-button-click

Comment: You could always attach a value changed event to the checkbox which calls a javascript function to a c# function which saves the boolean value to session. You can then retrieve the value on page load. Not very efficient but its a possibility depending on your scenario

Comment: are you binding any data in your page load method?

Comment: yes I am binding data to the listview into the page load method without checking  if (!Page.IsPostBack)  because I need to bind the page with the same data after deleting the specific data.I know that with Javascript it can be achieved but I don't know how to do it. Could you guys please help me on this?

Comment: Try to set the property `enableViewState` to `true` of the checbox.